# UserInterface freezes when BackgroundWorker is working

Tags: c#, user-interface, backgroundworker, freeze

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace IMDBWpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<Movie> movieList;
        BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
        private string searchText;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_doWork;
            bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_Completed;
        }

        private void bgWorker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                movieList = new Movies(searchText).movieList;
                searchBar.ItemsSource = movieList;
            });
        }

        private void bgWorker_doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                var loadingMovie = new Movie("src\\loader.gif", "Loading...");
                movieList = new List<Movie>();
                movieList.Add(loadingMovie);
                searchBar.ItemsSource = movieList;
                searchBar.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            });
        }

        private void searchBar_DataContextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            searchText = searchBar.Text;

            if(!bgWorker.IsBusy)
                bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a comboBox. Each element from combobox have a label and a image.

The comboBox is filled with elements from a webpage, process that takes some time until it's done.

The main problem is that when I write something in comboBox(yes, it's editable), my app freezes until the list with elements is created. To get rid of this freeze I tried to use BackgroundWorker, but it's not working...Any ideas why?
I tried to use threading on the class that generates the list, but nothing happens.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IMDBWpf
{
    struct Movie
    {
        public Movie(string movieImg, string movieT)
        {
            movieTitle = movieT;
            movieImage = movieImg;
        }
        public string movieTitle { get; set; }
        public string movieImage { get; set; }
    }

    class Movies
    {
        public List<Movie> movieList { get; set; }
        public Movies(string movieName)
        {
            if (movieName.Length > 0)
            {
                populateList(movieName);
            }
        }

        private void populateList(string movieName)
        {
            var webSite = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            var siteAddress = "http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=" + movieName + "&s=tt";
            HtmlDocument htmlPage = webSite.Load(siteAddress);
            movieList = new List<Movie>();
            int index = 0;

            while (htmlPage.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").ElementAt(index).Descendants("a").Any())
            {
                var movie = new Movie();

                movie.movieImage = htmlPage.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").ElementAt(index++).Descendants("a").ElementAt(0).Descendants("img").ElementAt(0).GetAttributeValue("src", "");
                movie.movieTitle = htmlPage.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").ElementAt(index++).InnerText;

                movieList.Add(movie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume `searchbar` is the `ComboBox`.

Comment: What is the count of `movieList` in `bgWorker_Completed`?

Comment: @xoxox Yes, it's the ComboBox
I use the class Movies to create the list of movies. That class is the reason of freeze and I need a different thread for it.

Comment: Have you tried to move `movieList = new Movies(searchText).movieList;` to the top of the completed method?

Comment: only dispatch UI changes. as everything you dispatcher is performed back at the primary UI thread (the one that can freeze)

Answer (score 4):

There are some issues with your design. The background worker calls bgWorker_dowork in a separate thread, but all logic is performed by the dispatcher and, hence, the logic is still performed in the ui thread.

I can't find where in your code the heavy logic is (is it the Movie constructor?). Anyway, move the heavy logic outside the invoke lambda method and just register it onto the combo box inside.

Comment: if(!bgWorker.IsBusy)
                bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); he calls in the event

Comment: Well, it's not possible... I want to make a searchbox like google. When you write something, it gives you suggestions. So I need the searchBar_DataContextChanged event, this is the reason why my two threads needs to work together.

Answer (score 0):

Like Micael pointed out, understanding how BackgroundWorker works is needed.

UI (UserInterface) controls are processed by the Main thread(UI thread) but the code inside DoWork is processed by Background thread.

However, if you wrap all the code inside DoWork with Dispatcher.Invoke, the BackgroundWorker is not a BackgroundWorker any more.

The solution is really simple that wrapping necessary things with Dispatcher.Invoke like as below.

```
private void bgWorker_doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    searchBar.Text= "src\\loader.gif", "Loading...";

    movieList = new Movies(searchText).movieList;

    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        searchBar.ItemsSource = movieList;
        searchBar.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    });
}

private void bgWorker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Error != null)
   {
       Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
       });
    }     
}
```

UI controls are such as comboBox, textBox, label, Grid, StackPanel, Button, etc.

BackgroundWorker is really convenient but a little bit understanding is required in the beginning.

Because the code inside DoWork was instructed by you to be done through Main(UI) thread, your application had to be frozen to complete the instructed work to be done.

And you don't need to repeat the code in Completed but better to do some other necessary work or handle the error if occurred.

Update-

I think one of possibilities is that there might be some issue when downloading from website.
Working with websites are always asynchrous meaning loading time would be different depending on internet traffic. But at this time, I guess the connection might have some problem and therefore, your apllication is waiting until the default timeout of web connection.

Comment: Where is movieList = new Movies(searchText).movieList; ?
This is the line that makes me problems

Comment: Just put it at some appropriate place inside DoWork. The point is freezing can be solved. And for your information, there're many already-made solutions free for the functionality like Google searching at the Sites like Github, Nuget.org though you already might know.

Comment: Little bit confusing during my own work. I don't know your exact codes but my recommendation is updated in my answer.

Comment: I added the other source code in my initial post. Please check it out

Comment: Hmm..just as quick glance. Sorry if I'm wrong..I think the backgroundworker only runs when the datacontext is changed but the datacontext is changed by the backgroundworker meaning never happens? Just test to run the backgroundworker in another simple button click event to see it works..

Comment: oh, wrapping is missing for searchBar.Text= "src\\loader.gif", "Loading..."; searchBar is UI control. Just test to run the backgroundworker in another simple button click event to see it works..And delete the datacontextevent code temporarily.